# What is the difference between function(vector<int> v) and function(vector<int>& v)?

Tags: c++, function, vector

While trying to perform insertion sort using vectors in C++, I discovered that when I used, it didn't perform the function:

```
void ins_sort(vector<int> v){
    //function body
}
```

Whereas when I did the following, it worked:

```
void ins_sort(vector<int>& v){
    //function body
}
```

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Pass by value vs Pass by reference

Comment: with vector<int> &, you are passing the reference which is original itself. Whereas  with vector<int> you just creating a copy ( pass by value)

Answer (score 10):

The `&` lets you pass parameters by reference. That is, you can modify them in the body of the function and still see them modified after you've called the function.

Without the `&`, you're passing a parameter by value. That is, the vector will be copied and you'll work with a copy of the vector while inside the function. After the function ends, you'll work again with the original vector.

Comment: True, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 2):

Basically passing by reference (`&`) passes *the same* `vector`, while passing by value (no-`&`) passes *a copy* of the vector. If the `vector` contains a lot of items, then there is a significant performance difference between the two. In addition, if the point is doing an insertion-sort, you probably want to sort the *same* vector, rather than a copy (unless you plan to return the copy, which will incur yet another performance hit).